# How to get text from a number in a select query

Tags: c#, mysql

there I have MYSQL DB, and it has an ID INT, however this identifier has a meaning in the system, I would like to get the meaning instead of the number for example something like this.

```
select ID from payments;
if(ID==0)
returns "No payment made"
else if(ID==1)
returns "Payment made accordingly"
```

Is it possible to do that ? or should I do it programatically? in the system?,
I'm using a datagridview in C# and that is why I want to get the result as a text and not a number from the query

Comment: Best practice here would be to keep the "display" in the UI.  Then you could have localization if you want.  The data and back end should just work with the value.

Comment: thank you @EhsanSajjad , did not know how to actually search this  in the forum thank you so much for that post :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
select case 1 when 0 then "No payment made" when 1 then "Payment made accordingly" end from payments
```

Comment: thank you for some reason the answer is in the comments XD ^^

Answer (score 2):

You Can use either `CASE - WHEN` or `IF` flow control operators.

Try the following `SQL`,

```
select case ID when 0 then 'No payment made' when 1 then 'Payment made accordingly' end as ID
from payments
```

Comment: thank you for some reason the answer is in the comments XD ^^

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is to

1. either have a lookup table for the possible id values within the payment table describing what each id value means and get this description via a join:

`select p.id, pd.description from payments p inner join paym_description pd on p.id=p.payment_id`

2. Or have these descriptions available in a resource file for the client application where the client application can look up the meaning of the value itself.

The reason is, if you ever need to change a description or add a new one, you need to edit code, and not a config table or resource file if you include the descriptions in the code. Not to mention, that if you have a large list, that will be a long case statement.

Comment: thank you for some reason the answer is in the comments XD ^^

Answer (score 1):

You can also use query as like

```
Select IF(ID=0,"No payment made","Payment made accordingly") as ID From payments;
```